# How to configure task cards on agile board in Youtrack?

Tags: agile, youtrack

do you know if there is a way to configure manually what is being displayed on the task's card on the Agile board in Youtrack?

[image]

In my case I would like to display some other field instead of "No subsystem", so it would look something like:

[image]

I know that when I change Agile board settings like "Board Columns" then other fields will be displayed, however they are "pre-defined".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A card displays first two custom fields in your project (excluding Priority, Assignee and State and some other that are displayed by other means), so you can you go to your_yt_url/editProject/project_key#project-tab=Fields and sort the list.

Comment: Is there a way to make it display only one field apart from detaching all applicable fields?

Comment: No, it's not possible.